# IE 10 Search Charm "search text"

Tags: windows-8

I want to know if this is possible in Windows 8.

I am on IE 10 or any browser, I select some text. I want that text auto populated in my Search Charm. Is it supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**. This is not a built in feature of Windows 8.